# High precision, but low recall on training data. What could be wrong?

Tags: neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network, precision-recall, train, errors-in-training

I am training RNN for timeseries binary classification. I observed that network has high precision, but low recall on both **training** and testing data. I tried multiple architectures, but same problem persists.

By knowing how data is constructed, I know that there can be multiple wrong data instances  in one of the classes.

What can I try generally, and what can I try in the case mentioned above?

Comment: Are your classes imbalanced?

Comment: In training set it is balanced.